# What is default hystrix timeout?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hystrix

I know that this is sounds strange, but I can't find the answer!

What timeout will be set for hystrix call by default if there is no any settings provided?

All questions about this are just that something doesn't work, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you ask about timeout settings for `HystrixCommand` then please check the [source code](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/blob/master/hystrix-core/src/main/java/com/netflix/hystrix/HystrixCommandProperties.java), there are bunch of other interesting defaults there. Default execution timeout is **1sec**:

```
private static final Integer default_executionTimeoutInMilliseconds = 1000; // default => executionTimeoutInMilliseconds: 1000 = 1 second
```

Comment: What happens if socketimeout is less than 800ms? Will it ever reach the hystrix timeout? Thanks

Comment: You mean socket timeout during command execution? If whole command completed within 1s - then it going to be considered as successful without impacting the circuit breaker.

Answer (score 0):

Hystrix has built in the following defaults:

Timeout for every request to an external system (default: 1000 ms)

Reference :

```
https://ahus1.github.io/hystrix-examples/manual.html
```

Answer (score -1):

The hystrix default timeout is 1second you can change that with :

```
#change default timeout to 10 seconds
ribbon.ReadTimeout=10000
```